# Reg ex matching a word

Tags: regex

I need to match only first two files, out of four files listed below:

1. ABD_DEF_GHIJ_20150611
2. ABD_DEF_GHIJ
3. ABD_DEF_GHIJ_FX_20150611
4. ABD_DEF_GHIJ_FX

I am using reg ex - `ABD_DEF_GHIJ(_\d{8}|\b)` and it's working fine. I would like to know if my solution is ok or there is any better alternate solution.

Comment: Your solution is quite fine. You could propably also change to ABD_DEF_GHIJ(_\d*) which means ABD_DEF_GHIJ plus 0-unlimited decimal characters

Comment: @blender `+` would make more sense to avoid a dangling `_`. `(_\d+|\b)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a negative lookahead which will exclude those having `_FX` following the initial alpha string

`^ABD_DEF_GHIJ(?!_FX)(?:_\d{8})?$`

see [example here](https://regex101.com/r/dL6zG1/5)

Comment: but this allows `ABD_DEF_GHIJskdkjds`

Comment: mine is so simpler than your's. Why a need for lookahead?

Answer (score 1):

Use anchors and make the number part as optional.

```
^ABD_DEF_GHIJ(?:_\d{8})?$
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/gN4oT1/1)

Comment: What's the difference between `^ABD_DEF_GHIJ(?:_\d{8})?$' and '^ABD_DEF_GHIJ(_\d{8})?$'

Comment: no difference, capturing group takes more steps but using non-capturing group would take min no of steps.

Comment: @my-thoughts why you rely on that particular site? For this to work, you need to enable multilne modifier.

Answer (score 1):

seems like you don't want to include files with `FX`, use negative look ahead, you can also append the optional `(_\d{8})?` if you think it's necessary

```
^ABD_DEF_GHIJ(?!_FX)
```

[DEMO](http://www.debuggex.com/r/B2TTBSQilRm4a0hb)

[DEMO 2](https://regex101.com/r/uW4aT5/1)

Comment: @my-thoughts , I don't know about regexpal.com . see the Demo in the answer which tests on the test data you gave

Answer (score 1):

Try this RegEx:

```
ABD_DEF_GHIJ(?!_FX_?)(_\d{8})?
```

On [regexpal.com](http://regexpal.com):
[image]

This also works:

```
\bABD_DEF_GHIJ(?!_FX_?)(_\d{8}|\b)
```